Unbounded operator on $L^2([a,b])$ with bounded inverse
Does there exist any unbounded operator $A$ on $Dom(A)\to L^2([a,b])$, with $Dom(A)\subseteq L^2([a,b])$ such that its range is dense (or onto) in $L^2([a,b])$ and it has an inverse defined on the range of $A$ that is linear and bounded?
All examples I tried that work for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ seem to fail in this case. For instance $Af=f''$ with $Dom(A)=H^2(\mathbb{R})$ works in that setting but fails when $Dom(A)=H^2([a,b])$.

I think adding boundary conditions would repair your example: define $D(A) = {u \in H^2(a,b): \ u(a)=u(b)=0}$ for $Af =f''$.

The inverse in this case would be $B^2$ with $(Bf)(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy$, right? If we let $Af=f'$ then $D(A)=\left{u\in H^1(a,b): u(a)=0\right}$ would also work with inverse given by $B$?

and moreover in both cases A does not only have a dense range but is actually onto $L^2([a,b])$?

For $Af=f''$ the inverse is more complicated to enforce the boundary condition at $t=b$. In both cases the range of $A$is all of $L^2$.

I think that this operator exists, my attempt:
Let us consider the Hilbert space $L^2([a,b])$ and suppose we are provided with an orthonormal basis $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. We can then define an unbounded linear operator $A$ on this space by its action on the basis elements:
$$A\phi_n = n\phi_n, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
The domain of $A$, denoted by $\text{Dom}(A)$, comprises all functions $f \in L^2([a,b])$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 |\langle f, \phi_n\rangle|^2$ converges. Formally, we have
$$\text{Dom}(A) = \left\{ f \in L^2([a,b]) : \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 |\langle f, \phi_n\rangle|^2 < \infty \right\}.$$
To demonstrate the unboundedness of $A$, we introduce a sequence of functions $f_k = \frac{1}{k}\phi_k$. It is clear that $f_k$ converges to zero in norm, i.e., $\|f_k\| = \frac{1}{k} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. However, the norms of their images under $A$ do not approach zero since
$$\|Af_k\| = \|k\phi_k\| = \|k\phi_k\| = 1, \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}.$$
This implies that the operator norm of $A$ is not bounded.
Moving on to the range of $A$, we assert that it is dense in $L^2([a,b]).$ To prove this, let us take an arbitrary $g \in L^2([a,b]$ and a positive real number $\epsilon$. We can always find an $N$ sufficiently large such that the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N \langle g, \phi_n \rangle \phi_n$ approximates $g$ to within an error less than $\epsilon$. Now, consider the function $h = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\langle g, \phi_n \rangle \phi_n$. It is evident that $h \in \text{Dom}(A)$, and $Ah$ yields the aforementioned partial sum. This confirms the denseness of the range of $A$.
The inverse operator $A^{-1}$ is defined in a similar fashion by setting $A^{-1}\phi_n = \frac{1}{n}\phi_n$. Its domain is characterized by
$$\text{Dom}(A^{-1}) = \text{Ran}(A) = \left\{ g \in L^2([a,b]) : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} |\langle g, \phi_n\rangle|^2 < \infty \right\}.$$
To establish the boundedness of $A^{-1}$, we perform a straightforward calculation for any $g \in \text{Ran}(A)$:
$$\|A^{-1}g\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} |\langle g, \phi_n\rangle|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle g, \phi_n\rangle|^2 = \|g\|^2.$$
This inequality shows that the operator norm of $A^{-1}$ is bounded by 1, denoted as $\|A^{-1}\| \leq 1$. This confirms the boundedness of the inverse operator $A^{-1}$, as required.

Thanks, this certainly does prove this class is non-empty.

The domain of $A^{-1}$ is equal $L^2.$

Let $A$ act on $D(A)\subset L^2(0,1)$ by $$ Af= x^{-1}f,\ D(A)=xL^2(0,1) $$ Then $D(A)$ is dense and $A$ is unbounded, The range of $A$ is equal $L^2(0,1)$  and $A^{-1}f=xf$ is bounded. The detailed explanation follows.
Assume $f\perp xL^2.$ Then $xf\perp L^2.$ Hence $xf=0,$ i.e. $f=0.$ Thus $D(A)$ is dense. Let $f_n=x1_{(0,n^{-1})}.$ Then $$\|f_n\|_2^2= \int\limits_0^{n^{-1}}x^2\,dx ={1\over 3n^3},\ \|Af_n\|^2={1\over n}$$ Therefore $A$ is unbounded. Clearly $A(xL^2)=x^{-1}(xL^2)=L^2.$ Finally $$\|A^{-1}f\|_2=\|xf\|_2\le \|f\|_2$$ i.e. $\|A^{-1}\|\le 1.$
